# Cannot upgrade nuget package due to Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration

Tags: sitecore-client, nuget

We are trying to install the following NuGet package: Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect

However, we are being blocked by this error message:

> Error Unable to find a version of 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration'
>   that is
>
> compatible with 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine 2.1.1
>   constraint: Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration (>= 2.1.1)',
>   'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables 2.1.1
>   constraint: Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration (>= 2.1.1)',
>   'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions 2.1.1 constraint:
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration (>= 2.1.1)',
>   'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Ini 2.1.1 constraint:
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration (>= 2.1.1)',
>   'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json 2.1.1 constraint:
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration (>= 2.1.1)',
>   'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Xml 2.1.1 constraint:
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration (>= 2.1.1)'.

Since Sitecore relies on this Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration NuGet package, we cannot remove it.

How do we get back to a state, where we can add NuGet packages?

Comment: Which version of Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect are you trying to install? Have you checked if some older version is compatible with Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration?

Comment: I checked if any of the older versions were compatible, but then I got the same error as in the question, just for a lower version 
 of Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration -  (1.0.0 I think).
I was trying to install Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect v. 3.1.0